# What can be a reason for VueJS Filter to return warning - is not a function?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-filter

I have a simple global **filter.js** filter:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import myService from '../../services';

Vue.filter('translate', function (message, ...args) {
    return myService.getString(message, ...args);
});
```

In **MyComponent.vue** template:

```
<div>{{"data.text" | translate}}</div>
```

In local environment it works fine, but while moving to producation I get this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: e._f(...) is not a function"
```

Comment: I don't have import to the filter.js file inside MyComponent.vue. Should I? the filter is global and it does work locally. What I'm missing?

Comment: You sure your filter is included in your production build? Where are you importing `filter.js`?